# How do you make two variables add together in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, addition

```
variable1 = 3
variable2 = "Hello"
print("variable 1 is", variable1)
print("variable 2 is", variable2)
print("Enter a new value for variable 1: ")
variable1 = input()
print("variable 1 is now ", variable1)
print("Enter a new value for variable 2: ")
variable2 = input()
print("variable 2 is now ", variable2)
variable3 = variable1+variable2
print("Variable 3 is the addition of variable 1 and 2 which is ", variable3)
```

How come variable1 and variable2 don't add up correctly when I run the program? Thanks for reading!

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: for when the user types in two value for each variable e.g 2 and 7, variable3 adds these two values together to get nine it says it is 27

Comment: You receive the variables as strings via `input()`.  You must convert them to int via `int()`, **then** do your addition.  If you don't convert to int, addition is read as concatenation for strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `input` returns the user entered data as string. So, when you use `+` operator on two strings, it concatenates them. You need to explicitly convert them to `int` like this

```
variable1 = int(input())
...
variable2 = int(input())
```

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU, so simple yet effective